# Text editor Ideas

Tags: c#, html, xml, richtextbox

I'm doing a bit research on gathering possible technologies to program a Text editor/Word Processor. The language used will be C# with the possibility to interop to unmanaged code via Pinvoke or Com. So far the Ideas I have come up with are.

1. Using Xml- Total Control of the process with the ability to use Xlst to style the document.
2. The rich Text editor Control - has out of the box word editing capabilities.
3. Html using Html Control with Design mode On - available formating tags already available and a easily distributable format.

I'm curious if anyone is aware of any other technologies or frameworks to build a Text editor I may have missed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are considering a simple rich text editor, there are components that are a little nicer that are based upon that text editor.  Sample from CodeProject [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CodeBox2.aspx)

Comment: I would go for kind of out-of-the-box editor, like e.g. DevExpress's or any other comercial one out there (there are lots of!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends from your technology of choise and licensing - if it is Silverlight or WPF, it's worth researching some components of the shelf - for example Telerik offers RadRichTextBox, which looks like can cover your requirements. Live Silverlight demos of word processor [here](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#RichTextBox/MSWord) and of data binding to HTML content [here](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#RichTextBox/Binding) - WPF variant is pretty much the same.

Comment: We already have  Devexpress, so after a bit of research on my own this seem like it would be the best route to take. Thanks for your response.